# Is it costly to leave the Console and Script features enabled in Firebug?

Tags: firefox, testing, development

For some time now, I've run Firebug constantly enabled to do quick DOM inspections, leaving the Console and Script panels disabled.

I'm just starting to use these two features so I don't have to keep using alerts for testing and debugging. I enable them while I use them and turn them back off when I'm done.

I'd like to know if these particular features can slow things down such that they shouldn't be left on round-the-clock. Like do they slow down page loads, use inordinate chunks of memory or something?

I don't see anything about it in the Firebug wiki.

Comment: This probably belongs on superuser

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes - FireBug is storing information which is meant to be static (i.e. only one instance is intended to be stored, however, FireBug stores *all* instances).

[Gmail](https://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?answer=77355) in particular will slow considerably and may even crash your FireFox instance.

Comment: Gmail warns you if Firebug is turned on. You can actually disable Firebug on certain sites if you want, but it's probably more sensible to disable it entirely when not in use.